# node.js read file in, parse to JSON and output

Tags: json, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm very new to anything much code related, but I'm on a slow and sometimes painful learning curve.

I have a file containing some json which I read into node.js parse and push to a web socket. The script works fine, but I only ever get one json object returned.

devices.json: (Complete file) Not every element has the same data contents, and there is any number of element objects within a data source.

```
{
   "element":"SENS01",
   "data":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T100"
   },
   "element":"SENS02",
   "data":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T088",
      "uid":"X1A1AA",
      "check_on":"2014/06/29"
   },
   "element":"SENS03",
   "data":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T000:",
      "uid":"X1A1AB",
      "check_on":"2014/06/29"
   },
   "element":"LED1",
   "data":{
      "type":"LED",
      "state":"0"
   }
}
```

The code which does the stuff is;

server.js:

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs');

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )

app.listen(8000);

    // Server started - load page.

function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('/var/www/html/dashboard.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading web page');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}


// creating a new websocket.

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log();


// 1st READ of json state file.

    fs.readFile('devices.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

// Parse/check its valid json.

    var dump = JSON.parse(data);

            socket.volatile.emit('MAP.room1', dump);

    });
});
```

When I connect to the socket the following is sent (as logged from the server console)

> debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"MAP.room1","args":[{"element":"LED1","data":{"type":"LED","state":"0"}}]}

I never get any of the other objects, only this one. I've had a look round the net about how to iterate over objects, but it was all largely meaningless to me :(

What I am trying to achieve is when you connect to the web socket every object from the devices.json file is pushed out 1 object at a time. So once this is working I would expect to see;

> debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"MAP.room1","args":[{"element":"LED1","data":{"type":"LED","state":"0"}}]}
>
> debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"MAP.room1","args":[{"element":"SENS03","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"T000:","uid":"X1A1AB","check_on":"2014/06/29"}}]} etc...

If I put a `console.log(data)` line in my server.js then I see the entire file as expected. Its only once its been parsed am I left with the 1 entry.

Can anyone please explain what's going on, and how I can best overcome this. It needs to be in a really simple way ideally using my own code/dataset as examples so I can understand 'what this means for me' A lot of the web examples and stuff I read tend to use different examples which just confuses me. I know the basics of declaring variables etc, and have an extremely limited experience with Ruby with a simple script to parse some push data received from an API but that's about it.

If you need any more context etc then please let me know, otherwise any help gratefully received.

Comment: The 'elements' are unique if it helps, but the objects and nesting in devices.json are fixed - Unfortunately the json is fixed and must be like that in order to be passed to d3 to update a rather complex DOM. The d3 stuff has been provided by someone else and I've been given that spec as to how my web socket should output in order to update the correct things. So without changing my source json (devises.json) is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out my data was actually JS objects represented as below in a flat format with every object seperated with a linefeed.

```
{"SENS01":{"type":"SEN","descr":"T100"}
{"element":"LED1","data":{"type":"LED","state":"0"}
```

Using linereader (from npm) I was able to  read the file in by doing;

```
lineReader.eachLine('simple.txt', function(line) {

                var dump = JSON.parse(line);

                socket.emit('MAP.room1', dump);

                });
```

That then output the required data from the web socket.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're using the same keys in your JSON. When the parser reads in that JSON, it continuously overwrites previous values of `element` and `data` and since those are the only unique key names, those are the only two values you see.

If you modified your JSON so that the same key names are not used on the same "level," then you would see all of the data you are expecting. Here's an example that makes it easy to iterate through each element:

```
[
  {
   "element":"SENS01",
   "data":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T100"
   }
  },
  {
   "element":"SENS02",
   "data":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T088",
      "uid":"X1A1AA",
      "check_on":"2014/06/29"
   }
  },
  {
   "element":"SENS03",
   "data":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T000:",
      "uid":"X1A1AB",
      "check_on":"2014/06/29"
   }
  },
  {
   "element":"LED1",
   "data":{
      "type":"LED",
      "state":"0"
   }
  }
]
```

Or if you can guarantee that the `element` values are always unique, then perhaps you could also do this:

```
{
  "SENS01":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T100"
   },
   "SENS02":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T088",
      "uid":"X1A1AA",
      "check_on":"2014/06/29"
   },
   "SENS03":{
      "type":"SEN",
      "descr":"T000:",
      "uid":"X1A1AB",
      "check_on":"2014/06/29"
   },
   "LED1":{
      "type":"LED",
      "state":"0"
   }
}
```

Comment: OK - I now understand what you mean having parsed the json at http://json.parser.online.fr/ with my input, and the output is exactly what I'm getting (so now I understand the point your making about the way devices.json is set up) Sadly I can't really change that at the moment so am still looking for some sort of work around. Or since my devices.json is a valid json file can't I somehow use that without `JSON.parse` ? I tried something before but my web socket output was full of /r /n and other escape chars so if there is a better way to get to the same end goal I'll be interested.

Comment: I ran a test with your json and while `JSON.parse` returns all the data I would still need a way to split each object before it got sent to the web socket. For the moment I need to work with the formatted json I have, and find a way to parse it all and send it to the web socket one object at at time. (e.g SENS01 then SENS02 then SENS03 etc. all the way through the devices.json file.

Comment: If you're not in control of the data, then you are going to have to find a third-party JSON parser (there are several on npm) that allows a reviver/callback and can pass in duplicate key=>value pairs.

Comment: Thanks - No at the moment I'm not in a position to be able to change the data. I'll have a look on npm anyway - if you have any pointers that would he handy. I'll leave this question open in case someone else has any ideas how to get to where I want to be.

Comment: Maybe its worth thinking about this a different way - if it helps me reach my goal. - I have all the objects in devices.json is there no other way I can read them in 1 object at a time. That way there is no issue about only getting 1 record from the parser as it will only be 1 record at a time fed in. Does that make sense?! lol